# how to get response toast

Tags: android, retrofit

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
.baseUrl(uri)
.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
.build();

```
    ayapi api = retrofit.create(ayapi.class);

    Call<model> call = api.adddata(namevalue,numbervalue,emailvalue,countryvalue,statevalue,cityvalue,pincodevalue,addressvalue,teams);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<model>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<model> call, Response<model> response) {
            
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),home.class));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<model> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),t.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are running background work so you can not run toast like that
instead, you can do this:

```
  ayapi api = retrofit.create(ayapi.class);
  // define toast before calling background work
  Toast toast = 
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

Call<model> call = api.adddata(namevalue,numbervalue,emailvalue,countryvalue,statevalue,cityvalue,pincodevalue,addressvalue,teams);

call.enqueue(new Callback<model>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<model> call, Response<model> response) {
        //call toast here
        toast.show();
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),home.class));
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<model> call, Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),t.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get Data from response.body() like this

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Inserted" + response.body(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();